# Create FluentIterable chain as a function, rather than immediately apply

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, guava

Is there a way to create a FluentIterable chain of functions, but delay binding to a specific collection?

For example:

```
Function<Collection<T>, T> chooseBy(Function<T, KEY> transform, KEY compare) {
    return FluentIterable.transform(transform).first(Predicates.equalTo(compare)).get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can create the `Function<Collection<T>, U>` (notice that it actually transforms to a `U`) yourself:

```
public static <T, U> Function<Collection<T>, U> chooseBy(final Function<T, U> transform,
                                                         final U compare) {
    return new Function<> {
        @Override
        public U apply(Collection<T> input) {
            return FluentIterable.from(input)
                    .transform(transform)
                    .firstMatch(Predicates.equalTo(compare))
                    .get();
        }
    }
}
```

If you actually meant a `Function<Collection<T>, T>`, that would be

```
public static <T, U> Function<Collection<T>, T> chooseBy(final Function<T, U> transform,
                                                         final U compare) {
    return new Function<> {
        @Override
        public U apply(Collection<T> input) {
            return FluentIterable.from(input)
                    .firstMatch(
                            Predicates.compose(Predicates.equalTo(compare), transform))
                    .get();
        }
    }
}
```